# How to get org defaults custom settings with SOQL

Tags: soql, javascript, query, ajax-toolkit, sforce.connection

I am developing custom button, I use ajax tooklit for getting some data, needed as url parameters. As part of it I want to query custom settings, but org defaults only.

```
var token = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Token_value__c FROM Security_Token__c").records.Token_value__c;
```

This is piece of my button javascript

Comment: You labelled this Apex, but perhaps you're talking about AJAX?

Comment: @sfdcfox yeah, you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is that you need to get the `Organization Id`. You can get `UserInfo` through the `AJAX Toolkit` via the `getUserInfo` method, and the resulting object has a property named `organizationId`. The actual `SOQL` you need then must match this value up with the `SetupOwnerId` field. The following works for me:

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js")}

var orgId = sforce.connection.getUserInfo().organizationId,
    soql = 'SELECT Id FROM MyHierarchySetting__c WHERE SetupOwnerId = \'' + orgId + '\'',
    defaults = sforce.connection.query(soql).records;
```